# Sonarqube MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException Duplicate Entry

Tags: mysql, sonarqube

I am getting the following error when running scans on several GitHub repositories. It does not seem to occur on the same repository whenever I run the scan job. I saw the other post that seemed related to this and would have added my question to that thread but was not allowed to comment on it. this error is stopping my Jenkins job from continuing so we are basically stalled with our scan progress.
Error details:
    Fail to process request localhost:8081/api/ce/submit?projectKey=KEY:Name&projectName=Name&projectBranch=branch org.apache.ibatis.exceptionsPersistenceException: ###Error updating database. Cause: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplciate entry '12-24334'admin' for key 'uniq_group_roles' ### This error may invovle org.sonar.db.user.RoleMapper.insertGroupRole-Inline ### This error occurred while setting parameters ### Cause: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQL

Comment: What's the version of SonarQube and which plugins are installed? Thanks

Comment: Version 6.0, Mysql 5.6.34
MySQL connector 5.1.39
Plugins:
C#  5.3.1
C++ Community 0.9.7
CSS 2.0
Git SCM 1.2
GitHub authentication 1.3
Groovy 1.3.1
JSON 2.0
Java 4.0
Java Properties 2.1.1
JavaScript 2.14
PHP 2.8
PL/SQL community 1.0
Python 1.6
SVN 1.3
Web 2.4
XML 1.4.1

Comment: so I suppose that GitHub authentication is enabled? Could you send the full logs for the error stacktrace? Thanks

Comment: How can I get you the stack trace? It is too long for this field.

Comment: You can use gist.github.com

Comment: Here is the [gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/85579845470bd1083e3a2ccffa364ad7)